# what is the DHCP?

Tags: networking

what is the DHCP? please details

Comment: you mean over and above what's at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol ?

Comment: I think question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: If the answer is at the top of a google search, it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP is a network service that assigns IP addresses to machines.

When you connect to a network, typically an Ethernet LAN or a wireless LAN, your computer asks the network "Can I have an IP address?". If a DHCP server exists, it will typically communicate the lease of an IP address, and send some other details, such as subnet masks, network routes, and DNS servers. The exact details are, of course, a bit more gory. [See the Wikipedia article on DHCP for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP).

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), perhaps. It is used to "automatically obtain IP addresses" among other things.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP means Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, That assigns automatically IP to network computers configured in DHCP pool

You can also reserve IP address from DHCP for particular network PC, you need to configure IP pool from that IPs DHCP will assign IPs to network computers.

Let me know if have any more questions about DNS or DHCP ?